# Can't add new input method

Tags: input-method

I use Ubuntu with LXDE and it's version is 14.04 LTS. Whenever I try to edit  my input methods I can remove them but I can't add a new one. I have only English input method and I want to add Turkish but I can't. The 'add' button is dark grey and I can't click on it.

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Are you connected to internet?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` in terminal and try again.

Comment: Well, I don't want to upgrade my whole system. Is there another command to update only the input method things?

Comment: This will not upgrade anything, it will just download the list of installable packages.

Comment: Thank you very much Pilot6. I can add input methods now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update package list first.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and try again.